# What availability is needed for an E-Mail server to not lose messages?

Tags: email, email-server, availability

Setting up an E-Mail server, I wonder, what if it goes down. Do I need a redundant setup in order to not lose incoming mails? Or would it suffice to make sure it doesn't go offline for longer than, say, a day?

Comment: How are the mails delivered to your mail server?

Comment: In general: the sending smtp server will retry delivery until either your mailserver confirms that  the message has been received  or it gives up and returns a failure report to the sender. What happens after the message has been received (and is stored to disk) on your mail server is of course your responsibility (your anti spam/virus may for instance still discard messages) and to comply to regulatory requirements and maintain a complete message archive for e-discovery or how to support recovery from users deleting messages from their INBOX is quite different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The place to look for an official answer to this question is [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321). Here is what RFC 5321 has to [say](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.4.1):

> Retries continue until the message is transmitted or the sender gives
> up; the give-up time generally needs to be at least 4-5 days.  It MAY
> be appropriate to set a shorter maximum number of retries for non-
> delivery notifications and equivalent error messages than for
> standard messages.  The parameters to the retry algorithm MUST be
> configurable.

So, if your server stays down for even three days, you shouldn't expect any mails to be lost, but they will of course get delayed.

A couple of advantages to having two MXs on different networks are:

- You avoid most emails getting delayed when one of the two is down.
- You have less risk of emails unable to be delivered when connectivity problems unbeknownst to you prevent a single sending server from reaching one of the networks hosting an MX of yours.

Comment: Huray for quoting the official RFC instead of my source, i.e. Wikipedia.

Comment: @Tom Thanks guys, this is surprisingly specific! Really cool, and indeed I'm most interested on the receiving end. BTW, I recently setup a server and one of the receiving filters (SPF or DKIM) wasn't configured correctly yet and I noticed already that the mail provider GMX was resending once an hour or so until that was fixed

Answer (score 6):

When mail servers have to deliver emails to you(r mail server), they must maintain a queue for when your mail server is offline. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#Protocol_overview):

> Fully capable SMTP servers maintain queues of messages for retrying message transmissions that resulted in transient failures.

The [Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html#hammer) also provides some more information on this.

Thus, as long as your mail server doesn't stay down for too long, you wont lose any emails. That being said, a redundant setup is of course better so you receive the emails almost instantaneously and you can keep sending out emails as well.

**Edit:** Sending out emails can be done by a completely different server. Your question was only for receiving email so that server going down does not necessarily impact your capability to send emails.